# how can I upgrade from version 11.04 to a newer one?

Tags: 11.04, upgrade, versions

I am a new user and I am not a computer expert. I tried to follow the steps on one of the the Ubuntu support pages, but it was not helpful (page did not work). Could some one help me, please? Thanks, Ceci.

Comment: sudo apt-get upgrade

Comment: @karel I think that question is about how to install new software in an older release, whereas the OP wants to upgrade to a new supported release (12.04 or up).

Answer (score 0):

General solution for such situations is to do several dist-upgrades to the next release until you reach supported version. For your issue, you need to update to 11.10 release then to 12.04. Then you have to decide if you want to have LTS version or the latest one which is 13.04. Of course, you need all transitional releases to be downloaded and burned to CDs, or you have to use Ubuntu old-releases site to make transitional upgrades.

Answer (score -2):

First update your ubuntu 11.04 with all required updates by
sudo apt-get update
then 
sudo apt-get upgrade
If any new version available it automatically intimate you to upgrade

Comment: FYI: sudo apt-get upgrade updates your CURRENT version. sudo apt-get dist-upgrade upgrades your version to a new one.

Comment: @ScottGoodgame It doesn't. You'll still have to follow more steps (e.g. editing sources.list) before it will perform a distribution upgrade.

Comment: I know I was just giving him a command to look up if he wanted to know how to learn how to do it...